# HTTP Post response causing error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http, post

I am executing a POST request from the browser to my service which succeeds with the status code `201 Created`. The application snippet that does that is the following. I can see it in the database that the fired JSON object was successfully stored.

The problem is that AJAX call never goes into `done()` part, but always ends up in the `fail()` part, even though the resource was created.

***JavaScript that fires AJAX***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // on-click listener
    $("#btn-submit").click(function(e) {
        // obtain data from the form
        var employee = {
            FirstName: $("#input-first-name").val(),
            LastName: $("#input-last-name").val(),
            BirthPlace: $("#input-birth-place").val(),
            CurrentPlace: $("#input-current-place").val(),
            Gender: $("#input-gender").val(),
            Department: $("#input-department").val(),
            OIB: $("#input-oib").val()
        };

        // AJAX call on button clicked
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/",
            data: employee
        }).done(function(){
            alert("Successfully created new entry!");
        }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert("Fail!");
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

***JSON being sent***

```
{
"FirstName": "Tia",
"LastName": "Tuon",
"BirthPlace": "London",
"Gender": "F",
"OIB": "19355864391",
"CurrentPlace": "Paris",
"Department": "21570"
}
```

***Service response tested with Postman***

```
access-control-allow-origin →*
cache-control →no-cache
connection →Keep-Alive
content-length →152
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Sun, 17 Sep 2017 11:27:39 GMT
expires →-1
keep-alive →timeout=15, max=99
location →http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/45
pragma →no-cache
server →Mono.WebServer.XSP/4.4.0.0 MacOSX
x-aspnet-version →4.0.30319
```

I am trying to log the error, but the output is very limited:

```
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} "error" ""
```

Why do I always end up in the `fail()` part of an AJAX call?

Comment: What are you returning from server on success? and on error?

Comment: can you try with `success: and error:` instead of `done and fail`

Comment: @Niladri I'm just returning a response message with the status code an the URI to the created resource. I'll try success and error and post what's the result of that in a minute.

Comment: i mean not using success or error callback/ method chaining but like below `success: function(data){ console.log(data)},error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errThrown){}`

Comment: @Niladri Yes, I know what you mean. And the output is exactly the same...

Comment: You have an absolute URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/` for the request URL, so unless your frontend code is also running on the `http://127.0.0.1:8080` server, that’s a cross-origin request, right? And unless the response from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/` includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header (which the list of response headers shown in the question seems to indicate it doesn’t contain), then your browser will block your frontend code from access to the response. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: What browser you tested? Is this result from chrome?

Comment: @CanetRobern Yes, Chrome.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Yes, I enabled CORS on the service-side, I am not sure however how the response with CORS enabled should look like - but I am indeed getting the values from service (JSON objects), ie for a GET request, and even a POST request succeeds (saves the object to the database), but just finishes in this fail block. I am supposing if CORS wasn't working I wouldn't be able to get any kind of response (as I couldn't prior to enabling it).